# I only have a guest account

Tags: guest-session

I just got a brand new dell XPS 13 and I went to set it up. I typed in the wifi password and realized I got it wrong. So I ended up hitting a button in the bottom right corner. For some reason it reset the computer and when it booted back up, it didn't save any of my info and I'm stuck with the guest account.

I don't have any internet connection in the guest account and can't set it up. What can I do to create an account and have full control of my laptop? The guest account won't allow me to create a new account.